# Trigger setter function automatically when value of input changes which is bound to an x-model

Tags: alpine.js, vue-reactivity

I have this in an input field :

```
x-model="product.price_USD"
x-on:input="$store.global_data.priceInINR = product"
```

where `priceInINR` is a setter and this works.

But it the real world scenario I don't want to add `x-on:input` everywhere - how can I set call this setter each time the `product.price_USD` changes ?

Comment: Maybe you can achieve something using [$watch](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch)?